# AWS Service Catalog - Passing Parameters to a Stack within a ProductStack

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-service-catalog

I have a Service Catalog portfolio that has a product deployed to it. The product is created from a basic AWS CDK Construct (S3 Bucket). I want to extend the product's usefulness by adding a parameter that a user can populate when consuming the product. This seems easy when I'm using a Construct in the ProductStack:

```js
export class ScConstructDemoStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const portfolio = new Portfolio(this, 'myportfolio', {
            displayName: 'Test Portfolio',
            providerName: 'Acme Corp'
        });

        const bucketConstructCFProduct = new CloudFormationProduct(this, 'SCProduct_construct_bucket', {
            productName: 'S3FromConstructWithParam',
            owner: 'me',
            productVersions: [{
                cloudFormationTemplate: CloudFormationTemplate.fromProductStack(new myS3ConstructProduct(this, 'S3FromConstructWithParam')),
                productVersionName: 'v1',
                description: 'Quick S3 Bucket'
            }]
        });

        portfolio.addProduct(bucketConstructCFProduct);

    }
}

class myS3ConstructProduct extends ProductStack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        const uploadBucketName = new CfnParameter(this, 'bucketNameParam', {
            type: 'String',
            description: 'Name of S3 Bucket',
        });

        const bucket = new Bucket(this, 'construct-bucket', {
            bucketName: uploadBucketName.valueAsString
        });
    }
}
```

This works.

However, I also have a CDK Stack that I want to add to Service Catalog. This stack is defined with a `CfnParameter` that I would expect to be available when provisioning the Product.

```js
export class ScCdkDemoStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const portfolio = new Portfolio(this, 'myportfolio', {
      displayName: 'Test Portfolio',
      providerName: 'Acme Corp'
    });

    const bucketCFProduct = new CloudFormationProduct(this, 'SCProduct_bucket', {
      productName: 'S3WithParam',
      owner: 'me',
      productVersions: [{
        cloudFormationTemplate: CloudFormationTemplate.fromProductStack(new myS3StackProduct(this, 'S3WithParam')),
        productVersionName: 'v1',
        description: 'Quick S3 Bucket'
      }]
    });

    portfolio.addProduct(bucketCFProduct);

  }
}

interface bucketProps extends StackProps {
  readonly bucketName: string
}

class myS3Stack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: bucketProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const bucket = new Bucket(this, 'mybucket', {
      bucketName: props.bucketName
    });
  }
}

class myS3StackProduct extends ProductStack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
    const uploadBucketName = new CfnParameter(this, 'bucketNameParam', {
      type: 'String',
      description: 'Name of S3 Bucket',
    });

    const deployStack = new myS3Stack(this, 's3StackProduct', {
      bucketName: uploadBucketName.valueAsString
    })
  }
}
```

When I synth this CDK code I get an exception which I read as *something* (probably the CfnParameter) is missing / undefined when the Stack is created.

```
Error: Artifact StackDemoStackS3WithParams3StackProduct88DBCA37 depends on non-existing artifact StackDemoStackS3WithParamDFB09CA4
    at /Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-artifact.js:1:1310
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at CloudFormationStackArtifact.get dependencies [as dependencies] (/Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-artifact.js:1:1244)
    at CloudAssembly.validateDeps (/Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly.js:1:3861)
    at new CloudAssembly (/Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly.js:1:1219)
    at CloudAssemblyBuilder.buildAssembly (/Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly.js:1:6098)
    at Object.synthesize (/Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/synthesis.js:1:800)
    at App.synth (/Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/stage.js:1:1866)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/ben/code/sc_cdk_demo/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/app.js:1:1164)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)

Subprocess exited with error 1
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't pass a Parameter to a Stack like this or point out my daft mistake?

Many Thanks

nb. I'm new to TypeScript, the CDK repo this code lives in is [here](https://github.com/bendudz/service_catalog_demo)

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like there is an issue with dependencies between stacks. Your `myS3StackProduct` stack doesn't really need to be dependent on the `myS3Stack`. Instead, you can define the S3 bucket and parameter in the product stack like this:

```
class myS3StackProduct extends ProductStack {
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
        super().__init__(scope, id)

        upload_bucket_name = CfnParameter(self, "uploadBucketName", type="String",
                                          description="The name of the Amazon S3 bucket where uploaded files will be stored.")
        bucket = s3.Bucket(self, "myBucket",
                           bucket_name=upload_bucket_name.value_as_string)
}
```

This will remove `myS3StackProduct`'s dependency on `myS3Stack`.

Comment: Thanks for the time to answer my question. I completely agree I could just use the S3 construct. However this was supposed to be a simple demo of what I’m really trying to do. The stack I want to use is actually this one: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-eks-using-cdk-typescript